# Facebook API : Show Only Posts From People Who I Want

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if this can be done or not with Facebook API :

- Let's say I have a web application with 'login with Facebook' button.
- When users login with their Facebook account and they become my 'circle' on my web application, even though they are not my friend on Facebook, can I still get what they post on their wall and display it on my own web application?

for example these are people who involve : Me, Mom, Dad, and Adam.

Adam is my class mate, but I haven't add him on my Facebook. So, practically, he's not my friend on Facebook.

now, if Adam login on my web application using his Facebook account, and he become my 'circle', can I see all his Facebook post? on my web application..

PS : is it possible to filter what's on Adam's wall too? for example I just want to display only posts created by Adam himself, not tags from his friends.

That's all I want to know. And could you please kindly tell me which API suit for this purpose? because I see bunch of terms on Facebook API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the authenticated has granted permission, you can display their data in your web application. The data presented only works in the current session (whichever access token is currently being queried).

If you saved the access tokens for each user you would be able to see the data **as long as it complies with Facebook Developer Policy**: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data